# GarageBand auto stored wrong Apple ID

Tags: macos, garageband

*GarageBand was updated using a different apple ID than my own. Since then it will not let me use my own credentials to update.*

Once a new update came out for GarageBand it prompted me to enter in my credentials. The login box had the Apple ID that is **not my own** greyed out and filled into the apple ID box. It prompts me for the password but will not let me change the login. I use my Apple ID for all other applications but it will not let me update GarageBand with my own credentials. Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: I'd try deleting it [maybe zip it for safety] & go to the App Store; see if it will allow you to download a fresh copy on your own ID.

Comment: @Tetsujin I just noticed that this is happening for me with all the software that came preinstalled on my mac. Is there a way to switch the account for that stuff too? Most pre-installed applications will not let me uninstall them... i.e. Keynote, Numbers, Pages, iMovie… It would be a lot of work to go through and delete everything...

Comment: I think you might need to talk to Apple about it, especially if you've no idea what the other ID is. Otherwise, if you do know how that ID got onto there, there's little you can do - software licenses are per user & not transferable. If it's a family member etc, set up [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) to get around that limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the app and go to AppStore and try downloading it from your Apple ID . I had the same issue and now it’s resolved!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i solved it by entering:

1. my mac's username (you can find it by going to system preferences >> search and click on "user & groups >> your mac's name will appear)
2. and the password of my mac